# PyUSB code for FT232 only output rubbish chars

Tags: arduino, pyusb

I am testing my PyUSB code for Arduino, which uses FT232 as interface IC. The arduino mcu just prints some chars out in 9600.

After struggling with its documentation, I can get it work. However I can only read some rubbish chars from its EP.

```
import usb.core, usb.util

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0403, idProduct=0x6001)

if dev is None:
    raise ValueError("FT232 not found. Have U enable it in LibUSB filter driver?")

dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, 0x00, 0, 0, '')
dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, 0x01, 0, 0, '')
dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, 0x02, 0, 0, '')
dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, 0x03, 0x4138, 0, '') # libFTDI 9600 bps

cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
intf = cfg[(0,0)]
ep = intf[0]

while True:
    dat = dev.read(ep.bEndpointAddress, 64, intf, 100)        
    if len(dat)>2:
        print ""
        print ': '+ ''.join([chr(c) for c in dat])[2:len(dat)]
        for i in range(2,len(dat)):
            print '%02X'%dat[i],
        print ""
```

I am not sure about the dev.ctrl_transfer part, this code claimed from libFTDI. 0x4138 is used to set it on 9600bps.

I used to write these four sentences as:
    dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, 0x00, 0, 0, 0)
    dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, 0x01, 0, 0, 0)
    dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, 0x02, 0, 0, 0)
    dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, 0x03, 0x4138, 0, 0) # libFTDI 9600bps

But I got following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Downloads\SemiconDev\Freescale FRDM KL25Z\Software\libUsb\FT232_PyUSB.py", line 83, in <module>
    dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, 0x00, 0, 0, 0)
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 693, in ctrl_transfer
    a = _interop.as_array(data_or_wLength)
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\usb\_interop.py", line 135, in as_array
    a.fromstring(data)
TypeError: fromstring() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not int
```

I am still looking for proper setup for ctrl_transfer().